# I want to display all data in sqlite on command line using NSLog

Tags: ios

**I developed mobile app in iOS using objective c that stores data in sqlite and database has five columns I want to display all data in sqlite on command line using NSLog and my code here that selects data from my database:
please help me how to solve this.

```
NSString *strshow = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select *from data"];
    dboperation *ds = [[dboperation alloc]init];
    arrmaindata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrmaindata = [ds getalluser:strshow];
```

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", arrmaindata)

Comment: Thanks mr Reinier Melian It works

Comment: Added as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `%@` which is mean to be used to print objects

**code**

```
NSLog(@"%@", arrmaindata)
```

Comment: how to display specific column in my sqlite database on textfield please help me using objective c

Comment: change your sql sentence use `select "yourColumnName" from data` @MohamedAli

Comment: How to display the selected data on  textfield

Comment: you need to concatenate that data and convert it in NSString and pass it to your TextField.text

Comment: I tried and I did not get please give simple example

Comment: What are you using @MohamedAli FMDB?